# Setting smooth progress bar with CMFCStatusBar

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm using CMFCStatusBar to handle several different panes in the application Status bar and it works fine. 
However, I can't seem to set a smooth progress bar in one of its panes.
The application is SDI and the code goes like this:

1. In CMainFrame::OnCreate() the status bar is created with all defaults - m_wndStatusBar.Create(this),
2. Then I use m_wndStatusBar.EnablePaneProgressBar(3) to allow creation of progress bar in pane 3
3. m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneStyle(3, PBS_SMOOTH) is then used to set a smooth progress bar but is doesn't affect it and the progress bar remains with blocks !!

What am I missing ?
Any help ?